# Angular Directive - Transclude same content twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a new directive which needs to take the inner HTML of the element and use transclusion to place it into the template in two different places. I am running into errors when trying to use the transclusion function twice, or using it once and appending the cloned contents twice, as you can see by my code below:

```
.directive('toolbar', function () {

    return {

        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        transclude: true,
        template:   '<toolbar-main><div transclude-main></div></toolbar-main>' + 
                    '<toolbar-overflow><div transclude-overflow></div></toolbar-overflow>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller, transclude) {

            transclude(function (clone) {
                 element.find('[transclude-main]').replaceWith(clone);
                 element.find('[transclude-overflow]').replaceWith(clone);
            });

        }


    };


});
```

Is it even possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append cloned version of the `clone` if you want to have two copies, otherwise the second `replaceWith` will simply move `clone` element from the previous location to the new one:

```
.directive('toolbar', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        transclude: true,
        template: 
            '<toolbar-main><div ng-transclude></div></toolbar-main>' +
            '<toolbar-overflow><div ng-transclude></div></toolbar-overflow>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller, transclude) {
            // nothing here
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it cloned all the elements, but the second clone doesn't appear to "work", which I assume means that it hasn't been compiled/bootstrapped properly. I have a button in my toolbar which has ng-click="outerController.functionName()" and it fires when you click the button in the first copy, but not the second.

Comment: @jonhobbs ops, i worked too much today.. just don't need to manually transclude content (or you need to compile the second manually, of course). Instead just use multiple transclusion points with `ng-transclude`.

Comment: I tried using multi-slot transclusion as in the docs but I got an error saying the second slot wasn't being filled. Anyway, I think maybe the best way is for me to ignore transclusion and manually compile the element contents twice and use jQuery to insert them into the DOM. That would work, right?

Comment: and here is manually compiling the clone http://plnkr.co/edit/k2UB1o4CTHtZ1voS0OKN?p=preview

Comment: Thanks dfsq. Very helpful.

Comment: Ah, I was using named slots for the transclusion and trying to transclude the same content into two named slots. Your way is much simpler.

Comment: Hey dfsq, if you see this, would you be able to help solve a further problem with this solution which I put into a different SO question? I'm really stuck...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35527228/illegal-use-of-ngtransclude-directive-in-the-template-when-doing-transclusion-m